# Override jQuery Tabs CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have overridden something in the past and made it important in the CSS. (Long time ago)

[image: black hover color in jQuery tabs]

It wasn't a problem at the time, but now it is overriding the hover over color of active and inactive tabs (Yellow Arrow) to Black.

I need to get the color back to the original color.

Also I put in a data table in and used CSS positioning to move it

```
top: -40px
```

Where can I do the `bottom: -40px` in the tab window (Green Arrow)?

live site at http://www.loadmax.com/classics

Comment: Please include all relevant code and a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demo.

Comment: This is a good reason *not* to use `!important` in your CSS unless you really, really mean it. Instead, use a [CSS selector with greater specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Comment: Tried to reproduce on JSFiddle and cant reproduce it...

Comment: the top: -40 was on the div that i placed the datatable in. Inside of the tab window. now i want to decrease the tab window

Comment: I am using Ruby on Rails so all the style sheets get loaded... i even tried to over ride with a fresh version of Jquery-ui theme but since something is !important it still overides

Comment: I have the live site up that you can see http://www.loadmax.com/classics

Comment: The active tab isn't black for me on your site. Perhaps you have a cached stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It loads a CSS from this one file:

http://www.loadmax.com/assets/application-dccd11e61e21d60b4ecb60c0b2022ce7.css

And that includes the following CSS on line 57 and following:

```css
a:hover
{
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #666666;
}
```

From what Firebug shows me, that's your culprit. No `!important` anywhere.

Comment: Do you know how to reduce the active tab window?

Comment: I would redesign the sheet to place the Search after the buttons and not inside the next div. That way you would not have a problem because of the -40px (because you would not be using it.)

Comment: Also, as a side note, it looks like many of your header data (links, stylesheets, scripts) are defined in your body instead of the `<head>` tag.

Comment: The search feature is part of the DataTable and is auto generated when table is built... Thanks for the heads up on the links